# Why does this AmpScript not work?

Tags: ampscript, marketing-cloud

From reading the AmpScript Lookup docs and seeing numerous examples online it seems that the logic of a simple AmpScript lookup can be stated thusly: From {This Data Extension} Return {The Value In This Column} Where {The Value In This Column} Is {This Value}. So if I for example have a simple DE

```
id, first, last, favColor
1, steve, hamaker, green
2, megan, hartman, orange
3, jason, smith, blue
```

And I do a simple lookup like so

```
Set @FavColor = Lookup("fav_colors_de","favColor","id","id")
```

Shouldn't I be able to then use the value within @FavColor within an IF statement?

```
%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@FavColor) THEN]%%
Your Favorite Color is: %%favColor%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

But the issue is that regardless, I always have an empty value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the `id` variable in your lookup function.

Also, you're outputting a personalization string for `favColor` not the variable that you're setting in your AMPScript block.

Should be something like this:

```
%%[
var @id, @favColor
set @id = AttributeValue("id")
Set @favColor = Lookup("fav_colors_de","favColor","id", @id)

]%%

%%[IF NOT EMPTY (@FavColor) THEN]%%
Your Favorite Color is: %%=v(@favColor)=%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks for the insight - obviously 'id' needs to have a value..otherwise it's not pointing anywhere. Such a simple mistake!